# not getting all rows from the database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I have developed an autocomplete function in codeigniter but the problem is that if we type two letters, it matches 2 or more than 2 characters but it is only showing 1 record I don't know why is this happening. Can anyone help me out.

I have 3 records that matches criteria like this:

- Vehicles
- Heavy road Vehicles
- Small Vehicles

When I type *Ve*, it shows me *Design & Development* and when I type in *Beh*, it shows me only *Vehicle* as it should show all  three. All 3 records contain name *vehicles*, can any one let me know where I am doing a mistake

Here is my *php* model **Get_data.php**

```
public function result($keyword) {
        $get_data = $this->db->like('cat_name', $keyword);
        $get_data = $this->db->order_by("cat_id", "ASC"); 
        $get_data = $this->db->get('categories');

        foreach($get_data->result() as $data):
            $sport = str_replace($keyword, "<b>" . $keyword . "</b>" , $data->cat_name);
            $html  = '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $data->cat_name).'\')">';
            $html .= $sport;
            $html .= "</li>";
            return $html;
        endforeach;
    }
```

**My php controller**

```
public function getData() {
        $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
        $html = $this->get_data->result($keyword);
        echo $html;
    }
```

Here is the **ajax** query I used

```
function autocomp() {
var min_length = 0;
var keyword    = $("#skills").val();

if(keyword.length > min_length) {
    $.ajax({
        type     :  "POST",
        data     :  {keyword: keyword},
        dataType :  'text',
        url      :  "http://localhost:90/tufuturo/home/getData",
        success  :  function(data) {
                        $("#resultkeyword").show();
                        if(data == false) {
                            $("#resultkeyword").html("<li>No Results Found</li>");
                        } else {
                            $("#resultkeyword").html(data);
                        }
                    }
    });
} else {
    $("#resultkeyword").hide();
}
}

function set_item(item) {
    $("#skills").val(item);
    $("#resultkeyword").html("<li><b>"+item+"</b></li>");
    $("#resultkeyword").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update foreach loop only

```html
$html = '';
foreach($get_data->result() as $data):
            $sport = str_replace($keyword, "<b>" . $keyword . "</b>" , $data->cat_name);
            $html  .= '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $data->cat_name).'\')">';
            $html .= $sport;
            $html .= "</li>";
            
        endforeach;
return $html;
```

Comment: Awesome can you please point out my mistake ? i was thinking that i am returning only li and that will obviously return the last value so what and where i did mistake?

Comment: - you are assinging li to $html in loop so it will initiate everytime and also you are returning from loop which is return only first element from your result set

Comment: perfect so if i have to return all data of the loop i have to start the variable assigning outside the loop

Answer (score 2):

After return  type everything would be vanish. You write return inside foreach loop. Loop iterate only one time and return.

Need to concatenate start tag of `li` with `$html`

also return outside of foreach loop as

```
foreach($get_data->result() as $data):
            $sport = str_replace($keyword, "<b>" . $keyword . "</b>" , $data->cat_name);
            $html  .= '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $data->cat_name).'\')">';
            $html .= $sport;
            $html .= "</li>";

        endforeach;

return $html;// return here
```

Use `num_rows();` to check query return result or not as

```
$num = $get_data->num_rows();

if($num>0)
{

 foreach($get_data->result() as $data):
                $sport = str_replace($keyword, "<b>" . $keyword . "</b>" , $data->cat_name);
                $html  .= '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $data->cat_name).'\')">';
                $html .= $sport;
                $html .= "</li>";

            endforeach;
}else{
     $html="<li>NO result found</li>";
}

    return $html;// return here
```

Comment: Though you return outside the loop, it will return one value becoz in code you are assigning "li" to $html. So everytime $html will initiate and it will return last element as output

Comment: when not matching ny thing its getting an error undefined variable return and also showing 1 result only

Comment: @MarkAlan check answer using `num_rows`

Comment: Okay so my mistake was that i was only outputing the li only it means i will be getting the last value only right ?

Comment: Have you add `. ` before `=` at `$html  = '<li` ??

Answer (score 0):

try giving LIKE command the third parameter which let you place wildcard % in you desired place. I would suggest use 'after' in third parameter
change this line
$get_data = $this->db->like('cat_name', $keyword);
to

```
$get_data = $this->db->like('cat_name', $keyword,'after');
```

Comment: Still same when i typed in Ve it showed me Vehicles but only 1 record not other coming up i am returning inner li within the loop does it effect i believe the loop is not returning for me though